# Manage Audio files in a Music app

Tags: android, sqlite, audio, android-music-player

I'm developing an Android Music app.
In my app, when app start, I use a cursor to load all music file in SD Card and show them in a recyclerView but I think it is't a good way (a little bit slow). 
I see in Google Music app, it uses SQLite database to manage music file. So I think when app start, I will load all music file an save information to SQLite database. And in the next time app start, if in SD Card have a new music file (downloaded from some website) I also load all file and update to SQLite database again. 
Do you think it a good way to develop a music app ?
Could you have some suggestion for me ?

P/s : sorry about my English :D﻿

Comment: That's what [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) is for - it takes care of the database, finding new files, and so on for you. That's what Google Music uses, I believe.

Comment: Thank you. But when I run Google Music app in Genymotion and use Android monitor to find it's package. I see this app use a SQLite database and in this database have a "Music" table to save music file information.

Comment: Yes, maybe Google Music does use it's own database. However, the standard android music player, and other players do use the MediaStore. But I guess you should simply use what works best for you in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to apply you suggestion in my app.

Comment: all music player uses MediaStore, it stores music files data to SQLite DB